# GWT 2.5.1 mvn install error “Rebind result <class> must be a class”

Tags: maven, gwt

**Problem:** I run mvn gwt:compile on my GWT 2.5.1 project that I built with the gwt-maven-plugin and get the error Rebind result  must be a class in all the classes that I have that extends CssResource.

This class is one of them:

```
public interface MainShellStyle extends CssResource{

    public static final MainShellStyle INSTANCE =  GWT.create(MainShellStyle.class);

    public String txtCompanyName();
    public String txtCompanySlogan();
    public String txtCompanyMessage();
    public String topRibbon();
    public String mainMenu();

    public String btnEditContacts();
    public String btnEditGuestBook();
    public String btnEditPictures();
    public String btnEditHome();
}
```

My pom.xml is the following:

```
<!-- Dependecies --!>
<build>

        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for development mode -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <!-- Plugins -->

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>

                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <targetPath>js</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>

                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- URL that should be automatically opened in the GWT shell (gwt:run). -->
                    <runTarget>Webmetalmore.html</runTarget>
                    <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <module>com.ohapp.webmetalmore.Webmetalmore</module>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                    <style>${gwt.style}</style>

                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <!-- JS is only needed in the package phase, this speeds up testing -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <!-- End Plugins -->

    </build>
```

It's the first time I'm compiling an GWT project. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `GWT.create()` a `CssResource` interface, you have to reference it from a `ClientBundle` that you'll `GWT.create()`. The association with the CSS file is made from the `ClientBundle` method.

See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html